# How to set boot order on KVM (libvirt/virsh)?

Tags: virtualization, qemu, kvm, libvirt

How would you set the boot order on KVM when using libvirt/virsh? (Either via config or command)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Please take a look at the section [Operation System booting](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsOS).

The most common option is the BIOS bootloader where it allows you specifying boot order via changing domain XML. try command `virsh edit <your-domain-name>` then adjust the boot order with this example (copied from libvirt.org):

```
<os>
  <type>hvm</type>
  <loader>/usr/lib/xen/boot/hvmloader</loader>
  <boot dev='network'/>
  <boot dev='cdrom'/>
  <boot dev='hd'/>
  <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
</os>
```

Which means the boot order is:

1. boot from network like PXE boot
2. boot from CD-ROM if no PXE boot
3. boot from local hard disk if no PXE boot nor bootable CD

Comment: So technically yes this is the answer... however editing the config directly and restarting the container will fix it more permanently. I figured this out after a few weeks of toying around with it. Anyway I'll give you the points since you did have the answer.

Comment: I found that `virsh dumpxml` followed by `virsh define` did the trick. (I didn't want to be doing this in an editor.)

Comment: I found it can specify boot order via virtual machine manager as well. see step 4 of this link:  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA:Testcase_Boot_Methods_Pxeboot

Comment: Thanks. I am still confused. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505554/how-shall-i-change-boot-sequenct-of-a-virtual-machine-in-kvm

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple hard disks a better solution is to use

```
<boot order='1'/>
```

for the first device you want to boot and

```
<boot order='2'/>
```

for the 2nd etc

For more information see https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsDisks